# When I perform a speech-to-text on C# app I want to be able to do that as many time as I want. How can I do that?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, console-application, speech-to-text

I have a console app in which I am using the System.Speech.Recognition. I want to speak to a microphone and to take the text. So far I managed. But I Have more sentences like "How are you?" "What time is it?" and so on. The applications recognizes all of them but it exits after I spell the first sentence. I do not want this to happen, I want the app to recognize all my sentences spelled on various timestamps. Bellow is my code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NaoSpeechRecognitionEntities db = new NaoSpeechRecognitionEntities();
            var userInput = db.UserInputs.ToList();
            //List<string> userReplies = new List<string>();
            Choices userReplies = new Choices();
            foreach (var reply in userInput)
            {
                userReplies.Add(reply.Reply);
            }

        SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
        gb.Append(userReplies);
        Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
        sre.LoadGrammar(g);
        sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized);
        sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        // Start recognition.
        sre.Recognize();
    }

    static void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("Speech recognized: " + e.Result.Text);
        CurrentReply.currentReply = e.Result.Text;
        //NaoSpeechRecognitionEntities db = new NaoSpeechRecognitionEntities();
        //var userInput = db.UserInputs.Where(ui=>ui.Reply==e.Result.Text).SingleOrDefault();
        //var robotReply = db.RobotOutputs.Where(rp=>rp.UserInputId==userInput.UserInputId).SingleOrDefault();
        //CurrentReply.currentReply = robotReply.Reply;
    }
```

As you can see it is a console app, I tried on windows forms but no success so far. I also tried to put sre.Recognize(); in a infinite loop, or to use goto instruction but it still didn't worked.

Any help is highly appreciated. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I forgot to mention that the statements that I want to be recognized are fetched from a database via EF, not that relevant but to give you a better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically store your SpeechRecognitionEngine object `sre` in a private field, and call `sre.Recognize()` again from the event handler. You may run into the problem, that the Recognize() command can't be called directly. Then the easiest way is probably to recreate the RecognitionEngine, while disposing the previous one.

```
class Program
{
    private static SpeechRecognitionEngine sre;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RestartRec();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static void RestartRec()
    {
        if (sre != null) sre.Dispose();

        //Preload DB entities once, store in private field and add them again here
        Choices userReplies = new Choices();
        userReplies.Add("hello");

        sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
        gb.Append(userReplies);
        Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
        sre.LoadGrammar(g);
        sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized);
        sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        // Start recognition.
        sre.Recognize();
    }
    static void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Result.Text);
        RestartRec();
    }
}
```

That way, after something was recognized by the engine, it just starts listening again. You may need a ReadKey() to avoid the program exiting, since Recognize will only block one event in your main.

It seems to leak memory despite the `Dispose()`, so it may need work. But you get the basic gist.